# Add query string in route map URL

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am using Ember 2.7. Is there any way to specify query parameters in the route map URL

**router.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
    location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
    this.route('index', {path: '/'});

    this.route('books', function() {
        this.route('index', {path: '?page=0&perPage=25'});
        this.route('view', {path: '/view/:bookIdid'});
        this.route('new');
 });
```

The above code is generating following URL **"localhost:4200/books/?page=0&perPage=25"**, I am not sure why it is adding slash before the query params.

**Navigation**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
<li class="nav-item">
  {{#link-to "products.index" class="nav-link vf-nav-types"}} Product Types{{/link-to}}
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  {{#link-to "books.index" class="nav-link vf-nav-books"}} Books {{/link-to}}
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  {{#link-to "apps.index" class="nav-link vf-nav-application"}} Application {{/link-to}}
</li>
```

Any help should be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code is wrong.

```
this.route('index', {path: '?page=0&perPage=25'});
```

You need to consider `queryParams` so define `page` and `perPage` inside controller.`this.route('index', {path: '/'});` 
it will be added by default, you don't need to include this in `router.js`. [guide link](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/routing/query-params/)

Created [Sample Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/8754ffcb631343db72fbf1037fd3cf70?openFiles=routes.books.js%2C&route=%2Fbooks) for demo.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['page','perPage'],
  page: 1, //1 is default value
  perPage:25,
});
```

For `this.route('view', {path: '/view/:bookIdid'});` consider to implement dynamic segments. [guide link](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments)

It's good to follow ember convention for defining dynamic segments, instead of `bookIdid` replace it with `:model-name_id` .

Comment: Yes.Modified as per your answer.While navigating first time i don't see any query params in the URL.If i go back to some other links then navigating to this page i can able to see the query params with null value.It is not picking the default value.

Comment: /books?page=null&perPage=null ....2-scenarios 
1) Initial launching- I cannot see query params.
2) while navigating - I can see query params with null value (/books?page=null&perPage=null)

Comment: How are you navigating ? created [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/8754ffcb631343db72fbf1037fd3cf70?openFiles=routes.books.js%2C&route=%2Fbooks) you can check for implementation.

Comment: I updated my question you can see the navigation link. I didn't pass any query params so by default it should take default value.Am i right?

Comment: try this `{{#link-to "books.index" (query-params page=1 perPage=50) class="nav-link vf-nav-books"}} Books {{/link-to}}`

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply.Do we really need to pass query-params in link-to, By default it will not pick the default values? Also while looking into the "twiddle" i can see the following code "
  queryParams: { page: { refreshModel: true },perPage: { refreshModel: true }}," Could you please explain the benefit of keeping query params in route?

Comment: You dont need to define it but we should not change queryParams property to null or to something other than default if that is the case then we need to force  reset to default by mentioning it in link-to helper.  So please keep it in mind Controller is singleton object. whenever you change controller property ,`refreshModel: true` this will refresh page..

Comment: Now everything seems working fine but i don't see query-params in URL so i cannot bookmark my url, In the router params i can able to see the param value. Why it is hidding the query-params?I am running my app in incognito window that might hide the params for security reasons?

Comment: only for default value it will not be shown in the URl.

Comment: Dont forget to declare `queryParams:['page','perPage']` and p`age:1` and `perPage:25` in controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your continuous reply.It helped me a lot.I want one more assistance is it possible to pass query params via anchor tag ex) <a class="page-link" href="#" {{action "pageClicked" item.page}} (query-params page=item.page perPage=2)>{{item.page}}</a>

Comment: `<a class="page-link" href="#" {{action "pageClicked" item}}>{{item.page}}</a>`  and  handle `pageClicked` in controller .. like this `pageClicked(item){
 this.transitionToRoute('books.index',{ queryParams: { page: item.page, perPage: 25} })
 }`

Comment: I can't handle pageClicked it is inside ember-cli-pagination library do we have any other way?

Comment: i haven't used ember-cli-pagination may be you can give it try `{{#link-to "books.index" (query-params page=item.page perPage=25) }} {{item.page}} {{/link-to}} `

Comment: Thanks again for your reply.it's not possible to specify action in link-to?

Comment: You can't directly mention but its possible. `{{#link-to "books.index" (query-params page=item.page perPage=25) }} <span {{action 'pageClicked' item}}>{{item.page}}</span> {{/link-to}} ..[reference](https://ember-twiddle.com/c5415bf45e3110025991b5e3db33ec99?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C&route=%2Freports)

Comment: I have gone through ember-cli-pagination [file](https://github.com/mharris717/ember-cli-pagination/blob/04913e2f659653051d26cb1b6adec27d2d301107/app/components/page-numbers.js#L63) it seems like they are bubbling `pageClicked` function so we can mention our own pageClicked function that should be called.

Comment: i have created action "pageClicked" in my controller as well as component but no luck, It is not invoking my action.

Comment: Even i tried the following code
     `{{#link-to "books.index" (query-params page=item.page perPage=25)  class="page-link"}}
    <span {{action "pageClicked" item.page}}>{{item.page}}</span>
    {{/link-to}}`

But no luck it's not working

Comment: The code i posted in the above is working but clicking span will not propagate the click on the link even i tried `<span {{action "pageClicked" item.page bubbles=true}}>{{item.page}}</span>` but no luck why clicking span not propagating the click event to {{link-to}}?

Comment: check this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/c5415bf45e3110025991b5e3db33ec99?openFiles=templates.reports.hbs%2C)

Comment: i don't see any difference in my code with yours.Then why my code is not working?It's strange

Comment: may be extract that code alone and post it as separate question..you might get answer..check is there anything  preventing default event propagation..

Comment: Might be.Because inside the span i have a number.While clicking the number span action event getting triggered but URL is not changes.While clicking outside of the number URL getting change but span action is not getting triggered.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there's no way to do what you (at least up to Ember 2.8), `queryParams` are declared in the controller, like stated in the [documentation](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/routing/query-params/).

You have to declared them in the controller like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['category'],
  category: null //or some other default value
});
```

When navigating through your application you can you the `link-to`helper to set query params, like this

```
{{#link-to "someroute" (query-params category="something")}}Go!{{/link-to}}
```